# COUNTIFS statement, =COUNTIFS(V60:V91, ">="&0,V60:V91,"<="&30)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting a COUNTIFS statement,

```
=COUNTIFS(V60:V91, ">="&0,V60:V91,"<="&30).
```

I believe I'm making syntactical error, but I can't finding it.  Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could have included some data, but in any case I think you have an answer below.

Comment: What are your getting as a return?  Are you getting an error, or `0` or the wrong count?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your syntax. You have text-that-look-like-numbers in column V,

Comment: V60:V91 is formatted with Dates, and I want to get a COUNT of how many Dates fall within the range of 0 >= 30.  I'm getting a 0 , where I should be getting a 2, because 2 records fall within the V60:V91.

Comment: Dates?  You need to show some data, the issue is you think that the equivalents are looking at the day number, where it is looking at the whole date.  If you want the number of days that fall in the first 30 days of a month, you are not going to be able to use COUNTIFS().

Comment: place this formula somewhere and tell us if it returns true or false.  `=istext(V60)`  this will tell us if the value in V60 is a date a text or number that excel is displaying as a date.

Comment: =istext(V60) it reads FALSE...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments in your question, you can try this if you are trying to count dates where the day of the month is Greater than or equal to zero (which would be all days), and the days that are less than or equal to 30...so all days except the 31st.  If this is wrong interpretation, let us know.  The following formula is based on your dates being stored as numbers and formatted to display as a date and not a date stored as text.

```
=sumproduct((day(V60:V91)>=1)*(day(V60:V91)<=30))
```

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of days in column V60:V91.  I have it formatted as such, if there is not a "DATE", it doesn't appear.  For example, in the range V60:V91, there are only "5 Dates" that appear, of the 32 (V60:V91).  The resultant is the count of 5.

Comment: I updated the formula so that blanks which would be evaluated as zero are no longer counted.  I did this by changing the 0 to 1.  It could also have been achieved by changing `>=0` to `>0`.   Important point to note:  If there is a number in that range that is not a date and that number is between 1 and 30, its going to be counted as well.  To cover off dates that are 31st you should change the 30 to 31.

Comment: If you are trying to distinguish dates from other numbers, a different approach would be required.

Comment: We are getting there Ed ...   thank you for your patience...    =SUMPRODUCT((DAY(V60:V91)>=1)*(DAY(V60:V91)<=30)) this great...    but of the statement I need one statement that would in essence reduce that 5 to 2...   I'm going vaca for 1 week...   thank you for all your help...

Comment: can you edit your answer and show the five entries that you have?  I am assuming you have other entries in the V60:v91 range, but without seing the range at this stage its really hard to tell what refinements would be needed

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax. You have text-that-look-like-numbers in column V.

[image]

Note the right-alignment of the numbers in column V. These are true numbers and are counted by your formula in A1. Note the left-alignment of the text-that-look-like-numbers in column W. They are not counted by the same formula in B1.

Use Data, Text to Columns, Fixed Width, Finish on **your** column V to turn them into right-aligned true numbers.