# Working out # times combination of values occurs in different rows/columns

Tags: excel, combinations

I'm very new to Excel. 
I am doing a research project and it involves a fair amount of data analysis.

I have got a document with many variables but I want to look at 3 variables:
Headache, Seizures, Mental State Changes.
These are in different columns for >300 subjects.

For each subject, I've marked "Y" for Yes if they had a headache etc.

I want to work out how many times say "headache + seizure + mental state changes" occurs, how many times "headache" etc occurs in isolation.

I was wondering how I could go about doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `Countif()` or `Countifs()` function.

Comment: How would I input this if I wanted to work out specific combinations? (I.e. headache + seizure + mental state change - altogether)?

Comment: @Johnny, have you looked into the function suggested above? `COUNTIFS` is exactly how you do that. This is an entry level excel function so it would be worthwhile for you to learn how to implement! Please see [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function) for more info :)

Comment: Excel function help also has examples and there are Q&A on here as well, this is but one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45638358/4961700

Comment: Thanks so much guys. I'm so sorry for bothering you all, just totally new to excel and didn't know what to search.

Comment: Gotta start somewhere!